# How to pass video frames from c++ to chromium embedded framework(cef)?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I am trying to pass video frames from c++ to html page through cef
i have tried by ipc and Scheme Handler of cef but I could not got 
success any help!!

Answer (score 2):

I have done it three ways:
1) Mojo - passing shared memory handles to YUV video frames:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/media/mojo/common/mojo_shared_buffer_video_frame.h&q=media/mojo/common/mojo_shared_buffer_video_frame.h&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

2) Using the webrtc capture framework - check out
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/media/capture/video/fake_video_capture_device.cc&q=fake_video_cap&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=1

3) Appending it directly to the sourcebuffer - I don't recommend this approach as it breaks the architecture. I recommend #2 or #1